# A very basic swift app doesn't compile (source code straight from Apple)

Tags: ios, swift

I was following this tutorial, until the last step when the code did not compile: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=16

The error is for the line:

```
let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)
```

And the error reads:

```
Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Here is the source code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    // Create a place to render the filtered image
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    @IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Create an image to filter
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)

        // Create a random color to pass to a filter
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

        // Apply a filter to the image
        let filteredImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

        // Render the filtered image
        let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())

        // Reflect the change back in the interface
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Why isn't it compiling?

Comment: It's not compiling because of the reason the compiler gave you: an optional type was not unwrapped. The example probably used an older version of the SDK. Optionals are very well documented in the Swift language guide - you might want to look into that before continuing learning.

Comment: what version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 7.0.1   ......

Comment: The version of interest is the version of Swift but with Xcode 7.x it is Swift 2. Unfortunately most Swift code is version 1.x. There is an option in Xcode to convert to Swift 2, it is good but does not guarantee a full conversion, it is a good first pass.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the documentation for [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image), the image property is a UIImage optional (it might have been a non-optional in previous versions which is why the code is incorrect). This means you need to change the code to:

```
let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)
```

By using the exclamation mark, you're unwrapping the image property. You can read more about optionals in the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330). Note that if  photoImageView.image is nil, this will crash the program. You can use code like this to make sure that it has value:

```
if let photoImage = photoImageView.image {
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImage)
}
```

Comment: To add to this: The Forced-Value operator (`!`) is [syntactic salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#Syntactic_salt) to ensure you're aware that you're dealing with an optional value that might be `nil`, but you're choosing to forcefully unwrap it. If the value happens to be `nil`, this will crash your program.

Comment: @Gudbergur thanks! I try to gauge the OP's knowledge, and provide background information where it may more appropriate than just giving the solution

Comment: OP's knowledge in this case is practically nil but I can't proceed until I have at least the most basic app working, right?

Comment: Different error on a different line. At "let filteredImage...", the error is: "Value of optional type 'CIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' '?'?"

Comment: Read up on Swift optionals and you'll figure it out. It's basically the same error.

Comment: There are a couple optionals that need to be unwrapped. This line ` let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())` needs to remove the parens after the extent. I followed all of Xcode's suggestions and my problems were fixed.

Comment: I added a '!' after "let filteredImage = inputImage" and a new error popped up. At line "let renderedImage...", the error: "Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type 'CGRect'"

Comment: sounds like you are using the latest xcode with swift 2.0 and using an old tutorial with swift 1.0 syntax.

Comment: Yep I guess I'll find a different tutorial.

Comment: from that error it sounds like you just need to remove the () after extent

Answer (score 1):

**Working code here**

```
 //
//  ViewController.swift
//  PhotoFilters
//
//  Created by Young on 5/12/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 danghoaidanh. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    //create a place to render the filter image

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    @IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

        // create a image to filter

        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)



        //create a random color to pass to a filter
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314))/100)]

        //apply filter to the image
        let filteredImage = inputImage?.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

        // render the filtered image
        let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, fromRect: filteredImage!.extent)

        //reflect the change back to the interface
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code that worked for the current Swift version in Xcode 8

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

// Create a place to render the filtered image
let context = CIContext(options: nil)

@IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Create an image to filter
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)

    // Create a random color to pass to a filter
    let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

    // Apply a filter to the image
    let filteredImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

    // Render the filtered image
    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())

    // Reflect the change back in the interface
    photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3, Xcode 8

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

// Create a place to render the filtered image
let context = CIContext(options: nil)

@IBAction func applyFilter(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let img = photoImageView.image else { return }
    // Create an image to filter
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: img)

    // Create a random color to pass to a filter
    let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

    // Apply a filter to the image
    let filteredImage = inputImage?.applyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

    // Render the filtered image
    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, from: filteredImage!.extent)

    // Reflect the change back in the interface
    photoImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: renderedImage!)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```